# markers appear/disappear a few time when toggleing on

Tags: angular-google-maps

I am having an issue with the markers directive.  I start by loading it but keeping visible = false.  then I toggle it on and the clusters appear, disappear and then reappear.  this sometime repeats a few times.  I tried setting doRebuildAll to false but then they don't appear at all when toggle visible to true.  Here is my markup for the directive.  I have it in another directive so that I can just keep a list of different kinds of layers:

```
 '<markers models="mylayer.locations" coords="\'location\'" doRebuildAll="true" idKey="\'id\'" doCluster="true" fit="true" options="mylayer.options" click="\'onClick\'">' +
                     '<windows show="\'showWindow\'" doRebuildAll="false" disableAutoPan="true" data-ng-if="mylayer.options.clickable" ng-cloak>' +
                            '<div>hello</div>' +
                     '</windows>' +
                  '</markers>'
```

And the object:

```
var loc = { latitude: item.Latitude, longitude: item.Longitude };
var marker = { location: loc, label: item.Label, id: item.Id, value: item.Value,showWindow:false };
                 markers.push(marker);
var layer = new markersFactory(5,'Top 1000 Locations by TIV', markers, true, { visible: false });
```

Answer (score 0):

Turns out the problem happened when updating from version 1.1.0 of angular-google-maps.js to version 1.1.4.  Reverted and it works fine now.